# Getting The Best Out of Polymorphism in Java

Tags: java, polymorphism, abstract-class

I have the following problem:

Consider we have 3 classes :

- One abstract class named `Vehicle`
- One class named `Motorcycle` which extends `Vehicle`
- One class named `Car` which extends `Vehicle`

That means that `Vehicle` objects can hold both `Motorcycle` and `Car` objects.

I have one more class named `VehicleDatabase` which basically "simulates" a database ( I wish I could use databases but this is an university project) and holds an `ArrayList<Vehicle>` field named `db`together with some methods that provide some basic operations so I can interact with the database (CRUD operations and some others).

One method I want to implement is the `showVehicles()`. To simplify and get to the point of my question let's say that this method must simply print to the console the `.toString()`'s of all object specified by the function's parameter.

**Example:**

A menu shows up in the user:

```
Select which type of vehicles you want to be shown:

1.Motorcycles
2.Cars

Make your choice:
```

After that our function `showVehicles` must take a parameter e.g `showVehicles(CarSomething)` and print all the cars stored on the `db` ArrayList. I just really can't find an more elegant way to implement that function. Below is my current implementation:

```
public void showVehicles(Class<?> cls)
{
    for(Vehicle v : db)
    {
        if(v.getClass().equals(cls))
            System.out.println(v.toString());
    }
}
```

and invoke it like this : `showVehicles(Car.class)` or `showVehicles(Motorcycle.class)`.

Is there a better method to do this? Please give your suggestions. I just feel I don't use polymorphism as it should.

Comment: Well... now you know why there is no such a thing as an "Object-relational-mapper". Relational databases store data, while objects are about behaviour. In your small example, you are still able to determine that some `Vehicle` is a `Car` or a `Motorcycle`. This would not hold true (at least not if you do not store additional information) if you use a real database. To circumvent this problem, [JPA defines different methods to represent inheritance](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/persistence-intro003.html#BNBQN).

Comment: Did you consider just storing them in a `Map<String, Vehicle>` where String is the actual vehicle type?

Comment: @WJS you would need to use a `Map<String, List<Vehicle>>` to store multipe instances of each class or a `Map<Vehicle, String>`, storing the class-name as value, not as key. Also, I would recommend to store the `Class`-instance instead of the name of the class as `String`.

Comment: @Turing85.  I concur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possibility.

I create a `Map<Class<?>, List<Vehicle>>` to hold the inventory.

The map was created from a list of vehicles but it could be created by simply adding to the map outright.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

abstract class Vehicle {
}

class MotorCycle extends Vehicle {
   String name;

   MotorCycle(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
   public String toString() {
      return name;
   }
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
   String name;

   Car(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public String toString() {
      return name;
   }
}

public class CarMapper {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      List<Vehicle> list = new ArrayList<>();
      list.add(new MotorCycle("Honda"));
      list.add(new MotorCycle("Harley-Davidson"));
      list.add(new Car("Ford"));
      list.add(new Car("Chrysler"));

      Map<Class<?>, List<Vehicle>> inventory = list.stream().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(Object::getClass));

     }
}
```

Whether this is a reasonable approach or not is up to you (and others who comment).  You may still need a map to get the correct class from the user menu.

```
  Map<String, Class<?>>  menuMap = new HashMap<>();
  menuMap.put("Car", Car.class);
  menuMap.put("MotorCycle", MotorCycle.class);

  Class<?> lookup = menuMap.get("Car");

  for (Vehicle v : inventory.get(lookup)) {
     System.out.println(v.toString()); 
  }
```

Comment: I wouldn't say that this makes things more convenient in my approach but it sure is a better way to implement what I'm trying to do. Best answer so far, will accept it if something better doesn't come up.

Comment: I was originally going to do Map<String, Vehicle>  (I forget the List part) but @Turing85 kept me honest and also suggested using the `Class instance` as the key

Comment: I'm seeing the comments, kudos to @Turing85 too. I don't think there's something better that can be done to be honest, that's normally the job of relational databases and not Java's.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is not the way an object-oriented approach is usually used. Here is an example with polymorphic approach. The 'printName' function is defined in an abstract class (could be an interface in this case as well):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

abstract class Vehicle {
    public abstract void printName(); // virtual function
}
class Car extends Vehicle {
    public void printName() { // function implementation in the class Car
        System.out.println("I am a car");
    }
}
class Bike extends Vehicle {
    public void printName() { // function implementation int the class Bike
        System.out.println("I am a bike");
    }
}


public class T1{
    ArrayList <Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();

    void create() {
        vehicles.add(new Car());
        vehicles.add(new Bike());
    }
    void list() {
        for (Vehicle v: vehicles)
            v.printName();  // use the function at the show time
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        T1 t1 = new T1();
        t1.create();
        t1.list();
    }
}
```

There will be a big difference if you want to use a real database. The latter can only save `data` fields from a java class and restore them into the class. So, your application must know about the classes at read time and make sure that correct classes are filled with correct data. Serialization can help in this case.

Comment: But I think that this print every element of the ArrayList...That's not the defined behavior I'm expecting.